# Basic question in quantum information

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Say Alice has a given quantum state. As of now, it's a pure state. Can she now choose to entangle her pure state with another pure state that Bob holds? I guess I'm asking: is a given state in Alice's hand by default (by definition of that state) either entangled or not entangled with Bob's state. Or can she choose to entangle it while maintaining the integrity of her state.

Comment: What do you mean by "integrity of the state"?  If you act on a state, it changes.  Note also that Alice alone cannot entangle stuff with Bob.  Alice and Bob have to meet and act jointly on their quantum states.

Comment: Say, Alice chooses to perform some unitary operations on her quantum state.. or she chooses to measure her quantum state. Does the result of the aforementioned get affected by the fact that her state is entangled with Bob's state or not?

Comment: (i) Please edit your question to make it more clear.  (ii) How is this related to your question?  (iii) The result gets affected by the initial state, be it entangled or not.  Of course, if it is entangled, certain things might be generally different.  E.g., Alice can never get a unique outcome when measuring.